# Magento JoinLeft

Tags: mysql, magento, zend-framework, left-join

I'm trying to join a custom table to a customer collection.
The custom table is:

```
+---------+--------------------+
| user_id | linked_customer_id |
+---------+--------------------+
|       4 |                 12 |
+---------+--------------------+
```

I want to add the user_id to each item where customer_id matches linked_customer_id.

I've got the following now, but I'm receiving:

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.entity_id'

```
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addNameToSelect()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('brand')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_company', 'customer_address/company', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('shipping_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_vat_id', 'customer_address/vat_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('salesrep' => 'custom_column' ), 'main_table.entity_id=salesrep.user_id',
        array('user_id' => 'salesrep.linked_customer_id')
    );

    $this->setCollection($collection);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think that because `customer/customer` is an EAV model rather than a flat model, the table alias it uses is `e` rather than `main_table`:

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('salesrep' => 'custom_column'),
    'e.entity_id = salesrep.user_id',
    array('user_id' => 'salesrep.linked_customer_id')
);
```

You will be able to find out by debugging the select statement, e.g.:

```
echo (string) $collection->getSelect();
```

Comment: You are totally right. That was the case. The table alias is indeed `e`. Thank you for clear answer.